# Doctype declaration Internet Explorer error

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, doctype

I have this DOCTYPE declaration on my web page, and it is causing an error in Internet Explorer 8 and prior versions. I've used this DOCTYPE before and have had the page load with no errors in Internet Explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

This page is working fine in all other browsers. This is the error I receive from IE8 and earlier versions.

```
The XML page cannot be displayed.

Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button.

Unspecified error Error processing resource 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you be sending the page with the wrong MIME-type somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is probably invalid. Invalid XML should not be processed, except maybe by a repair tool. IE does this right. 
Please check your page using the W3 validator: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Found an overlooked XML portion way up in the file. Pretty embarrassing mistake to say the least! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Try the HTML5 DOCTYPE

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

It could be because the page isn't being sent with the XML mime type

Comment: Why just change the doc type? That is only a solutions if the page contains indeed only HTML5 markup.

Comment: It's more likely to be valid HTML5 than XHTML and often the HTML5 doctype is more forgiving.

Comment: Since the OP has successfully used this doctype before, I thought it was more likely meant to be XHTML. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers go into quirks mode if the xhtml is invalid but IE will display an error instead if you use xhtml instead.  I would suggest either fixing the markup or switching to xhtml-transitional or html5.